# How do I secure my PHP forms that communicate with my MySQL Server?

Tags: mysql, php, database, website, vulnerabilities

They are just the basic forms, they take in $input from the form and then store that directly in to the database, there is another form where it takes $input and searches for a hashed match for it.

How can I secure this?

`$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO MD5TABLE (plaintext, hash)`
`VALUES ('$plaintext', '$md5hash')";`

Comment: Learn to use bind variables and NEVER use input directly as you did in your question.  Search for prepare statements and bind variables.